# Buffer size of CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I am trying to get the size of CMSampleBufferRef from AVFoundation call-back

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

According to documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMSampleBufferGetSampleSize

```
size_t CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize ( CMSampleBufferRef sbuf );
```

If I understand it correctly, I should use this method to get buffer size. But
I always got 0 from the return. and It is said that "If there are no sample sizes in this CMSampleBuffer, a size of 0 will be returned." In this case, I wonder if AVFoundation framework does not provide a buffer size information or I mis-understand document.

A follow up question:
By the way, I wonder in this case if I could use

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

from pixelBuffer to get the size of sampleBuffer?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

If your `CMSampleBuffer` expected to contain an Image then you can do something like below

```
- (CGSize)sampleBufferSize:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
          CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
          size_t imageWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
          size_t imageHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
          return CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your AVCaptureSession?

Basically a CMSampleBuffer can contain multiple information.

- Raw image buffer (which you can extract using CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer)
- Audio buffer (which you have to extract using CMSampleBufferGetBlockBuffer)
- CoreVideo encoded image data buffer (also have to extract using CMSampleBufferGetBlockBuffer)

So you should first check if the `captureoutput` is what you wanted, and if it is and you expect an image, then you should get the image as `CVPixelBufferRef` then check the data size on the image using `CVPixelBufferGetDataSize`